# Basic Algorithm Analysis and Summation Notation

Tags: algorithm

So for a homework we had to count the number of steps in a piece of code.  Here it is:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n*n; i++)
   for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
      for (int k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
          sum++;
```

My prof (i think) explained that the number of operations in the 2nd line could be found using summation notation, like so:

```
n^2
Σ   x 4 + 3 
i=1
```

which would be 1/2(n^4 + n^2) x 4 + 3 = 2n^4 + 2n^2 + 3

but from just looking the line, I would think it would be something like 4n^4 + 2 (my prof said 4n^4 + 3, I'm not sure where the third operation is though...)

Am I doing the summation notation wrong here?  It made sense to me to do summation notation for nested for loops, but I don't know why it would work for a for loop by itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Actually even your prof result is wrong. The exact result is `3n^4+3n^2`.

To obtain that result simply consider:

[image]

All passages are pretty simple (the passage from step 4 to step 5 is immediate if you consider the formula for the sum of the firsts `n` natural numbers).

Answer (score 1):

I guess both you and your professor are wrong. According to my calculation (I might be wrong too) it should be **`3n^4+3n^2`**.

The outer most loop will run n^2 times. Taken this into consideration the inner loop will run 1 time for the first iteration and so on till `n^2`. i.e. from `j=1 to j=1,2,3,4 ... n^2`. If we sum the series `(1+2+3...n^2)` this becomes `(n^2(n^2+1))/2`.

So for n^2 iterations of outer loop the inner loop will execute  `(n^2(n^2+1))/2` times. The most inner loop executes six times for every iteration of the second loop. So by just multiplying `(n^2(n^2+1))/2` with 6 it evaluates to  **`3n^4+3n^2`**.

To check the answer let's take an example. Say `n=5`, run your algorithm and print the sum this will give 1950. Now substitute this value in the evaluated expression, this will be like `3(5^4)+3(5^2)` and again this evaluates to `1950`.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to calculate is this:

```
S = sum(i in 1..n^2) sum(j in 1..i) sum(k in 1..6) 1
```

Now, the innermost sum is obviously 6, hence we have

```
S = sum(i in 1..n^2) sum(j in 1..i) 6
  = 6 sum(i in 1..n^2) sum(j in 1..i) 1
```

The innermost sum is just the sum of the first i numbers, which you should know is `i(i + 1)/2`, giving

```
S = 6 sum(i in 1..n^2) i(i + 1)/2
  = 3 sum(i in 1..n^2) i(i + 1)
  = 3 sum(i in 1..n^2) (i^2 + i)
```

We can separate this into two sums:

```
S = 3 [ (sum(i in 1..n^2) i^2) + (sum(i in 1..n^2) i) ]
```

The second sum there is just our old friend, the sum of the first n^2 numbers, so expanding that is easy.

The first sum there is a new friend, the sum of the first n^2 squares.  You can google for that if you don't know it off hand.

Drop in the formulae, expand a little, tidy with a broom, and you should get your answer.

Cheers!

Comment: Wrong, when you calculate the result of the intermediate loop you say it's `i(i+1)/2` while it's simply `i`, since it's not the sum of the firsts `i` number but simply the sum of `1` for `i` times.